# AsyncTask ... class must be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(Params...)' in 'AsyncTask' still giving error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, abstract-class

How do I get the doInBackground() method to be implemented as an abstract method ? The IDE also says I require 3 arguments instead of just 1 for AsyncTask<...>

```
package com.example.a_phi.nowswap;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class EstablishConnection extends AsyncTask<String>{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public String doInBackground(String id) {

        String link = "http://213.251.43.215/addContact.php";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("id", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }

        }catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.print("MalformedURLException" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.print("IOException"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
}
}
```

How do I get the doInBackground() method to be implemented as an abstract method ? The IDE also says I require 3 arguments instead of just 1 for AsyncTask<...>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `doInBackground(String id)` to `doInBackground(String... id)`.
I also changed `AsyncTask<String>` to `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`, then it worked.

Comment: Please don't use answers for things that aren't answers.

Comment: That was supposed to be my answer

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) indicates that `AsyncTask` has 3 generic parameters: `<Params, Progress, Result>`.

> AsyncTask's generic types
>
> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> 1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> 2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
> 3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation. Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type `Void`:
>
> `private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }`

It looks like you intend for `Params` and `Result` to be of type `String` (per your signature of the `doInBackground` method), so your class should `extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>`, and implement `String doInBackground(String... params)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `doInBackground()` method has a different signature to what you are trying to implement, as [shown in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)).

Notice that the `AsyncTask` abstract class requires your method implementation to have the following signature:

```
doInBackground(Params...) // the "..." is to say, an arbitrary number of arguments
```

Rather than what you are currently doing, which is equivalent to this:

```
doInBackground(Param) // a method with a single argument only
```

If you update you implementation as follows, it should resolve your compilation issues:

```
// Update the method signature of doInBackground as follows:
public String doInBackground(String... ids) {

    String id = ids[0];

    /* Beyond this point, you can leave your current implementation as it is*/
}
```